# Printing out box of Hashtags(#) surrounding text

Tags: java, for-loop

I am trying to create a box of Hashtags surrounding a text bar.

Below is the desired outcome.

```
############################################################
#                                                          #
# 01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345 #
#                                                          #
############################################################
```

I have a for loop which creates the frame but I want the System.out.print with text to only show a maximum of 56 chars no matter the length of the input. Also I want the Hashtag# after the text to stay in its place even if the string is shorter then 56 chars.

This is my current loop. Not sure how to get desired effect

```
String str = tangentbord.nextLine();
    if (!(str.equals(null))) {
    for (int n = 0; n < 5; n++) {
        if (n == 0 || n == 4) {
            for (int m = 0; m < 60; m++) {
                System.out.print("#");
            }
        }else if (n == 1 || n == 3) {
            for (int y = 0; y < 60; y++) {
                if (y == 0 || y == 59) {
                System.out.print("#");
                } else if (y > 0 && y < 60) {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
            }
        } else if (n == 2) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
                if (i == 0 || i == 59) {
                    System.out.print("#");
                } else if (i == 1 || i == 58) {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                } else if (i == 2) {
                    System.out.printf("%-56s", str.substring(0,56));
                }
            }
        }
        }
        System.out.println();
```

How can I keep a **fixed** size of the "`#` **frame**" (independent of the input size)? (if the input exceeds 56 characters, it has to be truncated)

Comment: I tested your code and you have the wanted output. I'm not sure what's the problem here.

Comment: @Tunaki If the text output is longer or shorter then 56 chars the # after the text moves with the text length

Comment: @Tunaki also, if the string is longer then 56 chars it should not be printed out

Comment: You hardcoded the string.. It's the same length always...

Comment: Well as Perdomoff pointed out, everything is hard-coded (text, loop bounds...). What did you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `System.out.printf`:

Let's consider `String str = "012345678901234567890123456789012345678";`

- add spaces **before** the string:

  ```
  System.out.printf("%56s", str);
  ```

  Output:

  ```
  ############################################################
  #                                                          #
  #                  012345678901234567890123456789012345678 #
  #                                                          #
  ############################################################
  ```
- add spaces **after** the string:

  ```
  System.out.printf("%-56s", str);
  ```

  Output:

  ```
  ############################################################
  #                                                          #
  # 012345678901234567890123456789012345678                  #
  #                                                          #
  ############################################################
  ```

To be sure that the string is not too long, you can use the `substring` method.

E.g.:

- when you assign a value to `str`, just call the `subtring` method if its length is greater than 56 - `str=something;` becomes `str = something.length() > 56 ? something.substring(0, 56) : something;`

Comment: This helps alot, thanks. But I still have the issue that if the string is longer then 56 chars the # moves. I want all text above 56 chars to not show

Comment: @A.Bohlund , I added a possible implementation that covers that situation.

Comment: yes I see that, great help! Im not sure where the put .substring(0,56) to get it it work. Suppose str comes from sc.nextLine()

Comment: Somewhere you'll get the string in a `str` (like in my example). Instead of `str = something` use `str = something.substring(0,56)` (check for `null` before)

Comment: I edited the code, I get stringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 56 at String skrivut = str.substring(0,56);

Comment: I think I get the exception since the string is less then 56, or am I wrong?

Comment: @A.Bohlund , don't adjust your question according to the answers. I mean, the problem should be there, otherwise the question won't be "valid". Yes, that was the case. I updated the answer. Now it should work.

Answer (score 1):

This get's you there, assuming that the string is only one line...

```
public class HelloWorld{
    public static String boxIt(String s){
        String r = "";
        int l = s.length();
        int c = 0;
        while(c<=l+2){r+="#";c+=1;}
        r+="\n#";
        c=0;
        while(c<=l){r+=" ";c+=1;}
        r +="#\n#";
        r+=s+" #\n#";
        c=0;
        while(c<=l){r+=" ";c+=1;}
        r+="#\n";
        c=0;
        while(c<=l+2){r+="#";c+=1;}
        return(r);
    }
     public static void main(String []args){
        System.out.println(boxIt("Hello World"));
     }
}
```